# Select IP phone account for native dialer

Tags: sip

I have two different SIP accounts: one is my favorite, but is only available from my home network. The other should be used from all other wi-fi networks. In case that I do not have any wi-fi connection, I would like to use the regular telephone service.

I managed to setup both accounts as IP accounts in android (4.2, G Nexus, native SIP support). However, I can only define one of the IP accounts as primary. This means that I need to change the primary account manually whenever I leave or come home. Android only asks whether to use IP or not, but doesn't ask which IP account to use. Is it possible to change this behavior?
If possible, I would like to use the native dialer and no SIP app.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but you could try [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) together with the [Secure Settings](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.intangibleobject.securesettings.plugin) addon. The latter mentions "SIP: change call options" amongst its features; but it's not clear to me whether that could mean "enable/disable", or whatever. There's a free 7-day trial of *Tasker* available on their homepage for testing.

Answer (score 1):

Don't define any account as primary account. In that case phone ask from you at everytime which ip account would be used to call. I check it on htc sensation z710e while wifi is available. Its working fine.